# How to align horizontally scrollable data table cell and title to hold max width of the content in react native paper?

Tags: react-native-paper

This is my first time using react native paper. I am building a data table that should be horizontally scrollable.

Each cell might hold data that would be longer than the header title. I would like the column headers to take the width of the max content in that column so that the data below it is correctly aligned in the column.

Currently it looks like this. Please see the code below:

```
<ScrollView horizontal style={[globalStyle.marginTop16]}>
      <DataTable>
        <DataTable.Header>
          <DataTable.Title numeric>Location ID</DataTable.Title>
          <DataTable.Title>Name</DataTable.Title>
          <DataTable.Title>Address</DataTable.Title>
          <DataTable.Title>Status</DataTable.Title>
          <DataTable.Title>Action</DataTable.Title>
        </DataTable.Header>

        {locations &&
          locations.rows &&
          locations.rows.map(row => {
            return (
              <DataTable.Row>
                <DataTable.Cell textStyle={{alignSelf: 'flex-start'}}>
                  {row.locationId}
                </DataTable.Cell>
                <DataTable.Cell>{row.name}</DataTable.Cell>
                <DataTable.Cell>
                  {[row.address1, row.city, row.state].join(', ')}
                </DataTable.Cell>
                <DataTable.Cell>
                  {parseInt(row.status) === 1 ? 'Active' : 'Inactive'}
                </DataTable.Cell>
                <DataTable.Cell>
                  <TouchableOpacity>
                    <Text>Edit</Text>
                  </TouchableOpacity>
                </DataTable.Cell>
              </DataTable.Row>
            );
          })}

        <DataTable.Pagination
          page={page}
          numberOfPages={3}
          onPageChange={page => setPage(page)}
          label="1-2 of 6"
          optionsPerPage={optionsPerPage}
          itemsPerPage={10}
          showFastPagination
          optionsLabel={'Rows per page'}
        />
      </DataTable>
    </ScrollView>
```

[image]

Comment: I could not find solution to this so I decided not to use this solution - I didn't wanna use a library that is already limiting such a crucial functionality